# How do you scan a multidimensional array in a clockwise fashion in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, scanf

[image: The problem Im working on]

I was approached by one of my students working on a personal project, we are both currently learning C and we have been doing basic projects to further our knowledge.

As an mathematics lecturer my coding knowledge is limited.

Could someone please assist me with this recent problem we have been working on and include some small comments. Your assistance would be most appreciated.

PS The image of the problem is attached.

Here is the code I have managed to write

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*QUESTION 1*/

/*Initialise Array*/
int
main (void)
{
  srand ((int) time (NULL));
  int Area_Zone[15][15], Area_Zone2[15][15], i, j, k, l;
  for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 15; j++)
    /* Display the multidimensional array */
    {
      Area_Zone[i][j] = rand () % 3;
      printf ("%d\t", Area_Zone[i][j]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 1; j++)
      return 0;
  }
}
```

```c
/*QUESTION 2*/

// C program to print the array in a
// spiral form-                       

//This is code I had to scripkiddie which seemed similar to my application
 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chplot.h>
#include <math.h>

#define R 3
#define C 6
 
void ClockwisePrint(int m, int n, int a[R][C])
{
    int i, k = 0, l = 0;
 
    /*  k - starting row index
        m - ending row index
        l - starting column index
        n - ending column index
        i - iterator
    */
 
    while (k < m && l < n) {
        /* Print the first row from the remaining rows */
        for (i = l; i < n; ++i) {
            printf("%d ", a[k][i]);
        }
        k++;
 
        /* Print the last column from the remaining columns
         */
        for (i = k; i < m; ++i) {
            printf("%d ", a[i][n - 1]);
        }
        n--;
 
        /* Print the last row from the remaining rows */
        if (k < m) {
            for (i = n - 1; i >= l; --i) {
                printf("%d ", a[m - 1][i]);
            }
            m--;
        }
 
        /* Print the first column from the remaining columns
         */
        if (l < n) {
            for (i = m - 1; i >= k; --i) {
                printf("%d ", a[i][l]);
            }
            l++;
        }
    }
}
 
/* Driver Code */
int main()
{
    int a[R][C] = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                    { 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 },
                    { 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 } };
     
    // Function Call
    spiralPrint(R, C, a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", then come back and [edit] your question. What is your specific question? Are you stumbling with the algorithm? Do you get any compiler error or warning? Make sure to raise the warning level to the maximum, especially as a beginner.

Comment: When reading the articles that the busybee linked to, pay particular attention to what they say about code examples and the use of images.

Comment: @Dr_Luo - _bottom left quadrant (29;0)_ is nonsense in _a 15 x 15 grid_; first you need a sane problem description.